# How to move a chemfig figure up or down

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I want to centralize this equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

 % Tartaric acid code \chemfig{HO-[1](=[7]O)(-[2](-[3]OH)-[1](-[7]OH)(-[2](=[1]O)(-[3]OH)))}
    
$$2AlK(SO_4)_{2(aq)} + \chemfig{[,0.5]HO-[1](=[7]O)(-[2](-[3]OH)-[1](-[7]OH)(-[2](=[1]O)(-[3]OH)))}_{(\ell)} \longrightarrow \chemfig{[,0.5]KO-[1](=[7]O)(-[2](-[3]OH)-[1](-[7]OH)(-[2](=[1]O)(-[3]KO)))}_{(\ell)} + 2Al^{1+}_{(aq)} + 4SO_{4(aq)}^{2-} + 2H^{1+}_{(aq)}$$ 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the organic molecules with each other, you must start writing the organic molecules from the center part.
chemfig always adjusts the molecules by the point where they start. If you start in the middle, it will adjust in the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
     \[
     2AlK(SO_4)_{2(aq)} + \chemfig{[,0.5]HO-[7](-[6](-[5]HO)=[7]O)-[1](-[2](-[3]HO)=[1]O)-[7]OH}_{(\ell)} \longrightarrow \chemfig{[,0.5]HO-[7](-[6](-[5]KO)=[7]O)-[1](-[2](-[3]KO)=[1]O)-[7]OH}_{(\ell)} + 2Al^{1+}_{(aq)} + 4SO_{4(aq)}^{2-} + 2H^{1+}_{(aq)}
     \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[See more here -- Veja mais aqui](https://twitter.com/CrocoDuckBR)

To prevent molecules from being italicized, use the nhchem package, for example. But that implies some changes...

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document} 
     2 \ce{AlK(SO_{4})_{2 (aq)}} + \chemfig{[,.5]HO-[7](-[6](-[5]HO)=[7]O-[0,1,,,draw=none]\parbox{1cm}{($\ell$)})-[1](-[2](-[3]HO)=[1]O)-[7]OH} $\longrightarrow$ \chemfig{[,.5]HO-[7](-[6](-[5]KO)=[7]O-[0,1,,,draw=none]\parbox{1cm}{($\ell$)})-[1](-[2](-[3]KO)=[1]O)-[7]OH} + 2 \ce{Al^{1+}_{(aq)}} + 4 \ce{SO^{2-}_{4(aq)}} + 2 \ce{H^{1+}_{(aq)}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]